# Sentinel Images swath

Tags: sentinel-2

Swath of Sentinel image is 290km. But the images which we download comes only at 190km.

Where can be 290km images be downloaded?

Comment: Where do you have this information from? Isn't it more like 290*km* ? And the images are 100x100km afaik. The image are just cut in smaller pieces to be easier to handle. You could simply download more than one image and merge them yourself ...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out RoVo.. ok so its basically cut into smaller pieces?

Comment: Do you need the full swath image (i.e. all tiles covering a single swath acquisition)?

Comment: Yes, Is there any site available from I can get image with full swath?

Comment: A full swath in full resolution would be around 250 Gigabytes ... I very much doubt that there is a site where you can get that ... But you can get a URL list.

Answer (score 10):

Each Sentinel-2 datatake is cut in pieces to be smaller in size and easier to handle. The data is cut to match the [Military Grid Reference System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_Grid_Reference_System).  The pieces are called granules or tiles.

> For Level-1C and Level-2A, the granules, also called tiles, are 100x100km2 ortho-images in UTM/WGS84 projection. [...]
>   Products are a compilation of elementary granules of fixed size, within a single orbit. ([via](https://earth.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/product-types))

Until August 2016 (?), multiple Granules have been included in one product. Since then, each product includes just one granule.

You need to merge multiple granules to get a full swath.

[image: Level-1C product tiling]

([via](https://earth.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/product-types))

---

For searching and downloading of Sentinel-2 data, please read the answers to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190681/where-how-to-download-sentinel-2-images). You could search for all granules of one orbit and download the files to merge them by yourself. A full orbit in full resolution would be around 250 Gigabytes

Answer (score 2):

The following shows how to use [Google Earth Engine](https://earthengine.google.com/) to explore the Sentinel-2 granule files and download a composited image that covers the full swath width.

Sentinel-2's [MultiSpectral Instrument (MSI)](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/instrument-payload/) has an imaging swath width of 290km:

[image]

*Here is the code used to create the preceding image:*

```js
// Filter the Sentinel-2 image collection those collected on a single day.
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
           .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-01-02');    
// Display a "true-color" representation.
Map.addLayer({
  eeObject: s2,
  visParams: {bands:'B4,B3,B2', min:0, max:3000},
  name: 'true color'
});
```

However, [Sentinel-2 data products](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/data-products) are distributed in granules/tiles, which are 100x100 km2 ortho-images in UTM/WGS84 projections. The granules overlap, with the most significant areas of overlap occurring along the boundaries of UTM zones. The following screenshot illustrates this using semi-transparent polygons to show where the granule boundaries are.

[image]

*Here is the code used to create the preceding image:*

```js
// Display granule boundaries.
var granules_boundaries = ee.FeatureCollection(s2);
Map.addLayer({
  eeObject: granules_boundaries.draw({color: '006600', strokeWidth: 5}),
  name: 'granule boundaries'
});
```

Google Earth Engine has access to the full Sentinel-1 MSI collection of granules, which can be filtered to a specified period of time. The filtered collection can then be composited into a single image using the [ee.ImageCollection.mosaic()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagecollectionmosaic) method, and then exported as a GeoTIFF file. For example:

```js
// Export a specified region.
var export_region = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[21.7, 39.7],
                                          [21.7, 37.0],
                                          [27.0, 37.0],
                                          [27.0, 39.7]]]);
Map.addLayer(export_region, {}, 'export_region');

// The following line prepares a "true-color" image for download.
var image_for_export = s2.mosaic().visualize({bands:'B4,B3,B2', min:0, max:3000});

// Uncomment the following line to download the full set of bands.
//var image_for_export = s2.mosaic().toUint32();

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: image_for_export,
  description: 'test-export',
  region: export_region,
  crs: 'EPSG:32635',
  crsTransform: [60,0,300000,0,-60,4500000]
});
```

will export the following image covering the full swath width:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding to RoVo's excellent explanation of the tiling and grid system there is a way to find and download all products within a full swath.

If you want to download all tiles within the swath of a single continuous acquisition in a given MSI imaging mode the metadata you are looking for is the *datatakeIdentifier*. This can be found inside the downloaded archive in the [metadata.xml (example on AWS)](http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/10/S/DG/2018/2/4/0/productInfo.json).

In this example the identifier is `GS2A_20180204T103221_013690_N02.06`.

Using the DHuS OpenSearch protocol you can then use the full text search to find all products of this datatake. This will return the metadata of all 410 tiles in this datatake.

`https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/search?q=*GS2A_20180204T103221_013690_N02.06*`

To download all products of this datatake you could use the full text search of the OpenHub and use the download cart or alternatively using the Python package [`sentinelsat`](https://github.com/sentinelsat/sentinelsat).

```py
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI

api = SentinelAPI("$username", "$password")  # connect to the API
products = api.query(raw="*GS2A_20180204T103221_013690_N02.06*")  # full text search for datatakeIdentifier
api.download_all(products)  # download all 410 products
```

Answer (score -1):

The Following Android application provide more than 60 types of Satellite ,it's sensors Information as well as downloading process videos and their official website. Thank you.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tushar.gisdatasource

Comment: **Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own product must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the [position] of [company] that develops/distributes this software/test".